# SharePoint Online: Un-Requiring a Required Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a few fields that were required inputs when we created the SP list, but no longer need to be required when the new item is added. I'm using two custom content types in this list and have flipped this field to optional in both of them. The form no longer shows these fields as required until the user tries to enter the item and gets the error

[image: (screenshot of the state field as an example)].

When we try adding new items via quick edit or add/edit items through Power Automate we're hitting the same error, where SP is treating these fields as required. Does anyone know how to fix this, or what might be causing the mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a custom content type with site columns, there are two places where you can make a column mandatory.

**1. via the Content Type**

List settings > click the content type > click the column > select **Required** or **Optional**

You can also get to this setting via Site Settings > Site content types > click the content type > click the column.
[image]

**2. via the Site Column**

This is a different setting that you can access via Site Settings > Site Columns > click the column

[image]

These second setting will override the "Optional" of the first setting, i.e. if the setting in the second screenshot is set to "Yes", then the column will be mandatory, even if the option in the first screenshot is set to "Optional".

Comment: Hi, in this case they're only list-level columns and content types, so the columns aren't appearing in the site columns list. I also don't get the option you highlighted in part 2 when I open the list column settings.

Comment: How did you create a content type without site columns??? That is not possible. Is this site a sub-site of a site collection? Then you may need to go to the parent site collection Site Settings page to see the Site Columns.